# Why does symbol char(10) at the end of line lose?

Tags: sqlite, delphi-10.1-berlin

In my case, I have lost a symbol $A at the end of line when I get field in Delphi. I think, Problem is in FireDac components. I use Delphi 10.1 Berlin and Sqlite (I don't know a version). When I start up program below, I have result **3!=4** in message.
This is code:

```
FD := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
FD.Connection := FDConnection1;
FD.ExecSQL('create table t2 (f2 text)');
FD.ExecSQL('insert into t2 values(''123''||char(10))');
FD.Open('select f2, length(f2) as l from t2');
ShowMessage(IntToStr(Length(FD.FieldByName('f2').AsString))+'!='+FD.FieldByName('l').AsString);
```

Last symbol $A lost.
May be somebody explain me this strange behavior.

Comment: No dublicate, I don't want concatenate strings. I have lost a symbol $A.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your comment really helps me. It works. Now symbol is on its place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off the [`TFDQuery.FormatOptions.StrsTrim`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDFormatOptions.StrsTrim) property:

> Controls the removing of trailing spaces from string values and zero bytes from binary values
>   ...
>   For SQLite, this property is applied to all string columns